# saved_change_to_attribute and previously_new_record can't work with ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...

has_many :memberships, class_name: 'Member', dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user
```

I'm trying to detect when a new record is created, but I'm facing an issue with two different methods of creation.

The first method involves creating a record directly using the model, like this:

```
@member = member.new(...)
@member.save
@member.previously_new_record ---> true
```

When I save the record using this method, the previously_new_record mechanism works perfectly fine, and @member.previously_new_record returns true, indicating that the record is indeed new.

However, the second method involves creating the record through an ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy, as shown here:

```
@member = user.membership.build(...)
@member.save
@member.previously_new_record ---> always return false
```

In this case, regardless of whether the record is actually new, `@member.previously_new_record` always returns `false` after saving the record.

I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue.

I have conducted tests using debugging techniques and the Rails console, and it appears that the previously_new_record mechanism doesn't function as expected when the second method is used.

Comment: Not just you @spickermann, I see no difference between the first and second method

Comment: @spickermann I dont know why but by testing a lot of times, previously_new_record always return false :(

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post, the second way use @member = `user.membership.build(...)`

Comment: As far as I know, the second approach should work unless the `save` fails due to a validation error. Are you sure the record is actually persisted to the DB?

Comment: Is a `member.new` the of the same class as an `membership.build`? I would expect the one to return an instance of `Member` and the other an instance of `Membership`. And are there any callbacks defined on those records? What do the log entries look like for both snippets?

Comment: @spickermann I added some code to define class User. Both return same of Member class instance type.